# WheelView does not scroll inside a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I'm using [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Everything work well.

But when i add a WheelView in a ScrollView. I cant move the WheelView.

You can see this issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/issues/detail?id=5&can=1) . But in Android 4.0 this is still a bug

How can fix this?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, i found out the solution

This works like a champ

```
if (getParent() != null) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

don't use it on android look at this: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html